# onActivityResult data is null on OS 10 but not on 9

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an image selector feature that when I ran on samsung tab 8(OS: Android 9.0(PIE)) works fine,
but when I run it on OS >=10, gives me a null data on `onActivityResult`

Here's the function to select an image:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Log.e("SELECT FILE IF = ", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+" ~ "+Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

        Uri internalStorage = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/myfile/reports/dji/");
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", internalStorage);
        intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        isKitKat = true;
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), 1);
    } else {
        Log.e("SELECT FILE ELSE = ", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+" ~ "+Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT);
        isKitKat = false;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Uri internalStorage = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/myfile/reports/dji/");
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", internalStorage);
        intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), 1);
    }
```

And when I Log the `Intent data` inside `onActivityResult` it gives me null.
Also, the `getActivity().RESULT_OK`'s value is `-1`.

**EDITED**
I am calling the intent on a `DialogFragment`

**EDITED**
The build.gradle is:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Does INITIAL_URI work? Your construct looks unusable. Try without. And Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT works always.

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult` has been deprecated, this may or may not be your problem. The new way is a bit more complicated but its an all around better solution.

These links will help you with setting up the new way while dealing with `Activity`s.

You `registerForActivityResult` inside the `DialogFragment` and then like normal `setResult` in the `Activity`, your registered callback in the `DialogFragment` will pick up the result, if it hasn't been closed.

https://newbedev.com/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

This link is used when talking between `Fragment`s

https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragment-result-805a6b2522ea